# Manipulate a List given by the session in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am setting an attribute called "bikes" in the session, which is a List.
For instance, this code prints the firt element of the list :

```html
function affiche() {
   var myString = "${bikes.get(0).getName()}";
   alert(myString);
}
```

I would like to use for instance a for loop and use something like
"${bikes.get(i).getName()}";
but I don't find a way to do it.

Any ideas ?

Thank you by advance

EDIT : with a java page, i am doing

```
session.setAttribute("bikes", bikes);
```

the only way I found to access the List in my jsp page is to do something like

```
var st = "$bikes";
```

but this gives something like [(filePathToObjectPackage@543622), (filePathToObjectPackage@54328)]. I think those numbers are related to memory. I can be wrong, but i thought the only way to access an object inside that list was to do

```
var myString = "${bikes.get(0).getName()}";
```

If so, i would like to be able to call it for a number contained in a variable.

I hope this is clearer now ...

Comment: What is the `$` in this context, and `${.....}`?  And why do you have a java tag on this question?  I think more context would be helpful.

Comment: @psyLogic That is up for discussion. It looks a lot like ES6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: I edited my post, i hope this is clearer

Comment: Have you tried with the classical jsp syntax <% ... %> ?

Comment: This syntax enables java in the jsp, but i need this variable in javascript.
I just tried 
<script> var st = <% request.getAttribute("bikes"); %>
alert(st);
</script>
this prints undefined ... i am not sure that mixing javascript and java in the same line might give something interesting

Comment: I'm thinking something like <% int idx=0; %>  function affiche() {
   var myString = ""; 
   for (var i = 0; i < bikes.length; i ++ ){
      myString = "${bikes.get(idx++).getName()}";
      alert(myString);
   } 
}

Comment: The 'idx++' gives me a "parsing Error". bikes.length is not declared either, but i can get the value without any problem. Removing the "<% int idx=0; %>" line and replacing 'idx++' by 'idx' makes an alert with always the first element (bikes[0]) ... I don't know why. Even a line with <% int idx=2; %> makes it return the first element ...

Answer (score -1):

Do you have try in this way:

```html
function affiche() {
   var myString = ""; 
   for (var i = 0; i < bikes.length; i ++ ){
      myString = "${bikes.get(i).getName()}";
      alert(myString);
   } 
}
```

Comment: @psyLogic Sorry, I really don't understand how that piece of code could be java code...

Comment: you can embed the java code on the client side using jsp

Comment: I known but it doesn't seem jsp syntax and isn't clear from question. Jsp syntax is not:  <%= ... %> ?